# logistic regression in r outside range [0,1]

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, logit

```
lreg02 <- glm(formula = hizortalama ~ hiz24saatonce + dummysezon1 + dummysezon2 +
  dummysezon3 + dummydilim1 + dummydilim2 + dummydilim3 + yon + yonestimated +
  nem6max + nem24max + nem6range + nem12range + nem24range + nem6var + nem24var +
  basinc6max + basinc24max + basinc6range + basinc12range +
  basinc6var + basinc24var + temp6max + temp12max +
  temp6range + temp12range + temp24range + temp6var + temp24var,
  family = binomial("logit"), data = dftrain)
pred <- predict(lreg02,dftest)
```

i am using glm function an i choose binomial as family, but in prediction i get results outside the range [0,1] any suggestions ?

Comment: How about `predict(lreg02, dftest, type = "response")`? By default, predictions are on the scale of the linear predictor.

Comment: my bad. using predict does not work here

Comment: @baris did you read the comment above?

Comment: The manual page for `predict.glm`, which is the function you are implicitly invoking here, explicitly states about the `type` argument that "The default is on the scale of the linear predictors; the alternative 'response' is on the scale of the response variable. Thus for a default binomial model the default predictions are of log-odds (probabilities on logit scale) and type = "response" gives the predicted probabilities."

Answer (score 7):

By default, `predict.glm` returns predicted values on the scale of the link function (linear predictor). On that scale, we fully expect values to lie beyond the 0-1 limits of the response.

You have a couple of options:

1. if you only want the predicted values you can use `predict(model, type= "response")`, which will apply the inverse of the link function to the predicted values to map them back on to the scale of the response variable.
2. if you want standard errors to form confidence intervals, you are better off working on the scale of the link function where you can form CI using the usual method from linear models and then manually map the predicted values and confidence interval limits back on to the response scale by applying the inverse of the link function yourself.

If you want to do 2. above, you can grab the inverse link function from the fitted model using:

```
linkinv <- family(model)$linkinv
```

This is a function and hence you can do:

```
pred <- predict(model, newdata)
linkinv(pred)
```

to do the mapping.

The `family(model)$linkinv` stays the same no matter what GLM you fit in R if it has implemented the `family` concept in the same way as `glm()`. the `gam` function in **mgcv** for example follows this way of working so this works the same with that package as with `glm()`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to access the link function from glmmTMB models given `family(modelname)$linkliv` returns `NULL`?